# An extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ to an interval $[0,p]$ with $p \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, real-numbers

I had a curious question bouncing around my head the other day.
I asked myself if there were numbers with similarly nice properties to something like $e$ in a finite field, along the lines of $\mathbb{F}_p$.
But because these finite fields tend to lack the structure of continuity of something like $\mathbb{R}$ I started to think about an extension by using the interval $[0,p] \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the added structure that $p \equiv 0$ 
(I was thinking about cutting a segment out of the real number line and glueing it together at $0$ and $p$).
Would that be a well-defined structure somewhat analogous to a like "pseudo"-finite field? And if that structure is a thing, how would one go about defining the analytic tools needed (for example a limit) to define interesting properties like $\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x$ or $cos(\pi) = 0$.

I am only in my second semester in the subject so I am not too familiar with advanced mathematics, and I would be really curious how these operations would behave in these circumstances or if this even can logically be a thing.

Comment: my first thought was that you can define functions from $f: [0,p] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and then pretend it's periodic with that period.  these are well-defined and have the usual derivatives etc.  and the obvious follow-up would be Fourier Transform.  however if you are thinking of $f: [0,p] \rightarrow [0,p]$ where the codomain also wraps, that might make it a bit more interesting...

Comment: And then you can define for $z\in[0,p]$ the exponential function $\exp(z):=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}z}$, which also wraps around. But now you haven't retained much structure from $\Bbb{F}_p$, and in stead your space looks more like a circle. How would you extend such a construction to field extensions of $\Bbb{F}_p$?

Comment: See also [p-adic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_analysis), even though $p$-adic numbers have characteristic zero, not $p$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ is a ring, you can transfer its ring structure to the isomorphic group $n^{-1}\mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{Z}$, obtaining the multiplication $n^{-1} (a\bmod n) \times n^{-1} (b\bmod n) = n^{-1} (ab \bmod n)$. The addition is compatible with that of $(2n)^{-1}\mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{Z}$ and $(mn)^{-1}\mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{Z}$, but the multiplications are not compatibles. Thus you can't extend in some natural way the ring 
$n^{-1}\mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{Z}, +, \times$ to a ring $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}, +, \times$ or $\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}, +, \times$